# How to exclude target folder from maven source packages generated with mvn deploy?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

When I run mvn deploy it seems like the generated source packages include target folder with its content. Really appreciate any clues on how to avoid this.

POM file:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-stratos/blob/master/pom.xml

Thanks

Comment: First clean up your pom files. Using old plugin (maven-assembly-plugin, don't use incremental-build plugin cause maven-compiler-plugin already supports that) and many other things. Take a deep look about defaults of plugin parameters. Don't use maven-surefire-plugin for integration tests (use maven-failsafe-plugin)..define plugins via pluginManagement in a single place etc. There are many violations against best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some investigations I found the cause of the problem. The issue was with the maven assembly plugin version 2.2-beta-2. Upgraded it to 2.2.1 and the problem was solved. Thanks khmarbaise for your feedback!